# Angular "ng:areq" error, factory issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've set up an Angular Factory and Controller to pull images off Instagram using their API. I'm getting an error when trying to load the page but cannot seem to figure out the issue. My html, app, routes, factory, and controller code is below. I left the quiz controller out as it's functioning properly. I think the issue may reside with the factory as I am new to using them.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <base href="/">

    <title>Starter Node and Angular</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- custom styles -->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/controllers/QuizCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/InstaCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/InstaFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container navvy">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Frank Social</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'InstaFactory', 'QuizCtrl', 'InstaCtrl']);
```

appRoutes.js:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'QuizController'
        })

        // quiz page that will use the QuizController
        .when('/quiz', {
            templateUrl: 'views/quiz.html',
            controller: 'QuizController'
        })

        // insta page that will use the InstaController
        .when('/insta', {
            templateUrl: 'views/insta.html',
            controller: 'InstaController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

InstaCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('InstaCtrl', []).controller('InstaController', function($scope, Instagram) {

        $scope.example1 = {
            hash: 'angular'
        };

        $scope.example2 = {
            hash: 'fit'
        };

        $scope.example3 = {
            hash: 'food'
        };

        var instagramSuccess = function(scope, res) {
            if (res.meta.code !== 200) {
                scope.error = res.meta.error_type + ' | ' + res.meta.error_message;
                return;
            }
            if (res.data.length > 0) {
                scope.items = res.data;
            } else {
                scope.error = "This hashtag has returned no results";
            }
        };

        Instagram.get(9, $scope.example1.hash).success(function(response) {
            instagramSuccess($scope.example1, response);
        });

        Instagram.get(9, $scope.example2.hash).success(function(response) {
            instagramSuccess($scope.example2, response);
        });

        Instagram.get(9, $scope.example3.hash).success(function(response) {
            instagramSuccess($scope.example3, response);
        });
});
```

InstaFactory.js:

```
angular.module('InstaFactory', []).factory('Instagram', function($http) {
        var base = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";

        var clientId = 'MY-CLIENT-ID-HERE';
        return {
            'get': function(count, hashtag) {
                var request = '/tags/' + hashtag + '/media/recent';
                var url = base + request;
                var config = {
                    'params': {
                        'client_id': clientId,
                        'count': count,
                        'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                    }
                };
                return $http.jsonp(url, config);
            }
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. I moved my routing logic into the appRoutes.js file, but forgot to delete a reference to a controller from my partial .html file. Once I removed this ng-controller reference from the html everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your application structures seems to be wrong as modules are used for packaging code that is reusable for example you are defining a new module to just add a factory in it just added it to the app module you should think of modules as a main function and use factory or service for specific behavior as you do with Instagram factory.